# Use value of CLI variable as the name of a host_vars variable?

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to use the value of one Ansible variable as the name of another variable so I can extract a value from its list?

host_vars:

```
this:
  does: walk
  says: hi

that:
  does: run
  says: hello
```

On the CLI when I run the playbook, I add `-e="thing=this"`.

In the playbook, I've tried all manner of things to expand the variable `thing` to its value `this`, then use `this` to extract the value of `does` in the `host_vars` file.

Using the variable name directly obviously works:

```
- name: Check what the thing does
  debug:
    msg: "{{ this['does'] }}"
```

But the following do not:

```
{{ thing['does'] }}
{{ {{ thing }}['does'] }}
```

Those, plus several other iterations I've tried all either throw an error or print out the literal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the *`vars`* lookup plugin to address variables indirectly. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup vars
```

For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', thing).does }}"
```

should give (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "thing=this"
  ...
  msg: walk
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    this:
      does: walk
      says: hi
    that:
      does: run
      says: hello

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', thing).does }}"
```

---

You can simplify the code further by putting all declarations into the *vars*. For example, into the *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/thing.yml
this:
  does: walk
  says: hi

that:
  does: run
  says: hello

_thing: "{{ lookup('vars', thing) }}"
```

Then, the simplified playbook below gives the same results

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: _thing.does
```